# О расчленении союза "невзирая на то что"

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

Союз ***невзирая на то что*** расчленяется по тем же правилам, что и союз ***несмотря на то что***, которые даются у Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138

Казалось бы, читайте правила и ставьте правильно запятые. Но в Нацкорпусе, как мне показалось, **ошибочных написаний значительно больше, чем правильных.** Почему-то люди не понимают этого правила в принципе и ставят запятые как кому нравится.

**В чем тут дело?** Правила неясно написаны? Этот союз особенный (на основе деепричастия, которое хочется обособить)? Может быть, раньше правило было другим?

А вот ответ "знающего" человека с сайта "Большой вопрос":

Союз ***невзирая на то, что*** обособляется запятыми. Запятая нужна перед ним, а также перед союзом «что», как уже начало нового придаточного предложения.
Например: *Они продолжали есть торт, невзирая на то, что их друзья уже ждали за дверью.*

**А это Нацкорпус:**

Павел Герасимович Лисициан, **несмотря на то, что** его голос ещё продолжал звучать прекрасно, вышел на пенсию. [И. К. Архипова. Музыка жизни (1996)]

Запомнилось и самому Владимиру Павловичу, **несмотря на то, что** оно вроде бы шокировало его. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

И вопрос: **В чем причина ошибок? Как помочь людям разобраться с темой?**

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, ошибки у писателей искать - дело сомнительное. Они так видят, так чувствуют - это мы должны прочитать то, что они хотели до нас донести, а не то, что мы хотим видеть сами. По Вашей ссылке у Розенталя читаем:

> В зависимости от смысла и интонации, логического подчеркивания
>   придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, наличия в
>   предложении определенных лексических элементов и других условий
>   сложный союз может расчленяться на две части: первая входит в состав
>   главной части как соотносительное слово, а вторая выступает в роли
>   союза; в этих случаях запятая ставится только перед второй частью
>   сочетания (т. е. перед союзами что, чтобы, как)[14]. Ср.: Он не
>   пришёл, потому что заболел — упор в сообщении делается на самый факт
>   неявки, причина ее не уточняется; Он не пришёл потому, что заболел —
>   на первый план выдвигается указание на причину неявки. ; Раскольников молчал и
>   не сопротивлялся, несмотря на то что чувствовал в себе достаточно сил
>   приподняться (Дост.); Несмотря на то, что ветер… свободно носился над
>   морем, тучи были неподвижны (М. Г.)

Так что это не ошибки, а их право, и это право им предоставляет и Розенталь в том числе. Вот ученикам нужно помочь разобраться с темой, только это означает научить чувствовать текст, видеть авторскую позицию.

Comment: У меня один небольшой вопрос, вот в этом предложении нет ЛИШНЕЙ запятой? "Запомнилось и самому Владимиру Павловичу, несмотря на то, что оно вроде бы шокировало его". [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]  У Розенталя стоит одна запятая: Раскольников молчал и не сопротивлялся, несмотря на то что чувствовал в себе достаточно сил приподняться (Дост.); Тогда вариант с расчленением будет таким: Раскольников молчал и не сопротивлялся несмотря на то, что чувствовал в себе достаточно сил приподняться. В обоих случаях вроде бы стоит одна запятая. Или нет?

Comment: Людмила, вы меня пугаете (вполне ожидаемым от многих других) употреблением выражения "в том числе": в числе кого находится Розенталь?  :)

Comment: Alex_ander, здесь пропущено,  что это право предоставляют им и лингвисты, Розенталь в том числе. Чуть сократила и так понятное, неряшливо, конечно, оформила, согласна. Как говорится, "спасибо, что делаете нас лучше" своими замечаниями.

Comment: Sharon, Вы не учли, что  предложный оборот с несмотря на, как правило, обособляется, не обособляется только при тесной смысловой связи с господствующим словом, после которого он находится:  Он это сделал несмотря на запрет матери. Это после ТО может ставиться или не ставиться запятая, а перед уступительным предлогом ставится обязательно.

Answer (score 1):

**Расчленение составных союзов по правилу Розенталя.**

А. **Исходные данные**

1) Придаточное предложение может занимать три позиции: в начале, в середине и в конце предложения.

2) Если придаточное находится в середине предложения, то составной союз не расчленяется.

3) Если придаточное находится в начале или в конце предложения, то составной союз может расчленяться или не расчленяться.

Исходя из этого, мы получаем **пять возможных схем предложений.**

Б.**Решение**

1) **Грамматическое правило расчленения**

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138

В зависимости от (различных) условий **сложный союз может расчленяться на две части:** **первая входит в состав главной части как соотносительное слово, а вторая выступает в роли союза.**

2) Пример: **Раскольников молчал и не сопротивлялся, несмотря на то что чувствовал в себе достаточно сил приподняться** (Дост.).

Для этого предложения возможны 5 схем (выделено главное предложение):

(1) Несмотря на то что Раскольников чувствовал в себе достаточно сил приподняться, **он молчал и не сопротивлялся.**

(2)  **Несмотря на то,** что Раскольников чувствовал в себе достаточно сил приподняться, **он молчал и не сопротивлялся.**

(3) **Раскольников**, несмотря на то что  чувствовал в себе достаточно сил приподняться, **молчал и не сопротивлялся.**

(4) **Раскольников молчал и не сопротивлялся**, несмотря на то что чувствовал в себе достаточно сил приподняться

(5) **Раскольников молчал и не сопротивлялся несмотря на то,**  что чувствовал в себе достаточно сил приподняться.

3) Пример: **Лошадь начинала уставать, а с него пот катился градом, несмотря на то, что он поминутно был по пояс в снегу.** А. Пушкин, Метель.

Для этого предложения возможны 4 схемы (выделено главное предложение):

(1) Несмотря на то что он поминутно был по пояс в снегу,  **с него пот катился градом.**

(2) **Несмотря на то,** что он поминутно был по пояс в снегу,  **с него пот катился градом.**

(3) **С него пот катился градом**, несмотря на то что он поминутно был по пояс в снегу.

(4) **С него пот катился градом несмотря на то**, что он поминутно был по пояс в снегу.

**Вывод:**

По Розенталю в современных правилах **нет варианта**: С него пот катился градом, **несмотря на то, что он поминутно был по пояс в снегу.**

Почему? Потому что здесь расчлененный союз **не разделяется по грамматическому правилу**, а полностью входит в придаточное предложение.

Comment: @ Sharon,так зачем же вы поставили запятую перед союзом?

Comment: Но я же цитирую неправильный вариант, который был у автора.

Comment: @ Sharon,все понятно...