# Есть ли в предложении лишняя запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

Вот предложение:

**Запомнилось и самому Владимиру Павловичу, несмотря на то, что оно вроде бы шокировало его.** [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

Я уже рассматривала это предложение в вопросе [О расчленении союза "невзирая на то что"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448001/%D0%9E-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE)

Прямого ответа я так и не получила, хотя считаю, что ответить мне может **любой пользователь русского языка, который работает с текстами**: школьник, студент, журналист, писатель, блогер и уж, конечно, корректор, редактор или учитель.

Я предполагаю, что **одна запятая здесь лишняя,** то есть возможны такие варианты расчленения союза (авторский выбор):

(1) Запомнилось и самому Владимиру Павловичу **несмотря на то, что** оно вроде бы шокировало его.

(2) Запомнилось и самому Владимиру Павловичу, **несмотря на то что** оно вроде бы шокировало его.

**Это так, или я ошибаюсь?**

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1) Вот Пушкин: Лошадь начинала уставать, а с него пот катился градом, **несмотря на то, что он поминутно был по пояс в снегу.**

2) Но мне эта пунктуация кажется **устаревшей,**  она просто сохраняется как авторская.

3) Дело в то, что Розенталь настойчиво подчеркивает, ч**то запятая может быть ОДНА.** http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxviii.html#sect108

**Такой подход соответствует правильному пониманию грамматики.** У нас составной союз. Если его расчленить, то **одна часть отходит к главному предложению, а другая к  придаточному.** Это как бы основной грамматический принцип расчленения, и он соответствует правилам Розенталя.

4) А В "Метели"  составной союз полностью отходит к придаточному предложению и **при этом расчленяется внутри этого придаточного предложения. Вот что неверно!**

5) А вот правильное расчленение: Несмотря на то, **что ветер… свободно носился над морем,** тучи были неподвижны. Здесь первая часть союза входит в главное предложение, а придаточное оказывается в середине.

6) У Розенталя нет таких примеров, как в "Метели". Вы цитируете Грамоту.ру http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?id=58_483&layout=item

Грамота.ру, как обычно, ни на что не ссылается, но между ними при решении этого вопроса **явное противоречие.**

Comment: Почему же? Грамота как раз ссылается на тексты художественной литературы. Кстати, вы приводите пример, в котором союз стоит в начале предложения. А в этой позиции иное пунктуационное оформление невозможно.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, я сама  отвечу на свой первый вопрос, чтобы рассказать, как я понимаю Розенталя.  На этом тему придется закрыть.

Comment: Грамота утверждает, что "***это обусловлено тем, что союз образован при участии отглагольного предлога".***

Comment: А из какого правила это следует?  Грамота не может пользоваться собственными правилами, у нее нет законодательных функций. Я не думаю, что этот вид составных союзов нужно исключать из общего правила, это может иметь только негативные последствия.

Comment: Это справочник, который составили специалисты Грамоты.ру. Справочник редактировали доктора, профессора. Видимо, они посчитали упомянуть об этом на том основании, что в примерах из художественной литературы встречается запятая.

Comment: Всё это замечательно, я часто пользуюсь этим справочником, но вот выделение отглагольных предлогов в отдельную группу выглядит странно. В Приложении даются правила, но они общие для всех видов союза. И уже потом следует статья "Некоторые закономерности". Там сказано: Анализ примеров из художественной литературы позволяет разделить составные союзы на 4 группы в зависимости от особенностей пункт. оформления. И мы видим, что в отглагольных союзах (в этих худ. произведениях) ставили дополнительную запятую и перед союзом ЧТО.

Comment: И что с этим делать? Писатели ставили так, а по современным правилам надо ставить по-другому, так к чему Грамота призывает остальных пользователей. Ну давайте считать это старой орфографией и не будем править классиков, но об этом нужно сказать четко и понятно. Как быть людям, пишущим сейчас, что будет считаться за ошибку у школьников, студентов, редакторов? И что они вообще знают о статье «"Некоторые закономерности"?

Comment: Вы почитайте ответ, который я получила на свой вопрос. Цитируется Розенталь, как будто это он одобрил такое членение отглагольного союза. Опять я что-то не учла, мне рассказывают про какую-то тесную связь уже предлога, а не союза.   Поэтому  совершенно немыслимо в этой и так сложной теме выделять еще четыре группы союзов с особым написанием. Причем они и не призывают выделять, а по-тихому приводят примеры согласно фактическому письму из художественной литературы. Где логика?https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448001/О-расчленении-союза-невзирая-на-то-что

Comment: Позиция Грамоты.ру интересная. Жаль только, оно лишь ссылаются на примеры из художественной литературы и никак не объясняют этот факт. Я постараюсь задать им вопрос, чтобы они прокомментировали свою позицию.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за участие в решении этой проблемы. Только вот действуют они странно: ссылаются на Розенталя,  цитируют его, а примеры приводят те, которые ему противоречат.

Comment: Серж, здесь надо поточнее спросить. Например: По Розенталю, если составной союз полностью входит в состав придаточного предложения, то он не расчленяется.  Но если в такой позиции поставить запятую перед ЧТО, то это будет нарушением правила Розенталя?

Comment: Sharon, да, конечно. Вы правы. Кстати, есть еще одно обсуждение с лингвистами. Вот. https://ask.fm/russian/answers/152574048828

Comment: Да. спасибо, значит, не мы одни  видим "лукавую" позицию Грамоты.

Comment: Грамота.ру упорно не хочет отвечать. Зато Грамма.ру ответила.  Ниже см. скриншоты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скриншоты их ответа.  Цветной скриншот второй ответ.

Comment: Вот такой ответ.  Посмотрите на тексты, там часто ставится запятая перед ЧТО.  Придуманное правило про предлог, который будто бы сохраняет свои свойства, войдя в союз.  Примеры, которые не имеют отношения к той структуре, про которую спрашивали. Ну что здесь можно сказать? Нет ответа на конкретный вопрос: почему расчленяется составной союз, который полностью вошел в придаточное предложение. Люди или не разбираются в этом, или не хотят вникать (некогда им). Значит, так и будем жить в таком пространстве, пока не наступят лучшие времена. Большое Вам спасибо за Ваше неравнодушие к языку.

Comment: @Sharon, меня удивило то, что сотрудник говорит о несовершенных правилах. Целый состав докторов-профессоров, которые работали над правилами, почему-то умалчивают об этом.

Comment: Работают, вероятно, исполнители, а доктора-профессоры только визы ставят.  Я вспоминаю свой опыт общения с таким профессором, когда я начала ему объяснять свою собственную "фонематическую школу". Очень долго (с полчаса) он меня вообще не слышал, говорил о чем-то своем, что ему интересно. Потом подумал и изрек: "У Вас не школа получилась, а языковая модель". Подумал еще и добавил: "Удивительно, однако, как Вы, вникаете во всё..."  Таким образом, чтобы "достучаться" до профессора, нужно проявить большое упорство.  А до современных докторов, вероятно,  не достучишься и вовсе.

Comment: @Sharon, возможно, вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

В приведенных вами примерах запятая не является ошибкой. Вот что пишет Грамота.ру.
Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом **«несмотря на то(,) что»,** выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. *При этом союз может целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но может и расчленяться, в этом случае запятая обычно **ставится и перед союзом (перед словом «несмотря»),** и между его частями (перед словом «что»). О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания, см. в Прил. 3.*
**Лошадь начинала уставать, а с него пот катился градом, несмотря на то, что он поминутно был по пояс в снегу. А. Пушкин, Метель.**

**Он, несмотря на то что был в упоительном чаду пива и вина, чувствовал, что несколько неприлично в таком виде и при таком действии находиться в присутствии постороннего свидетеля. Н. Гоголь, Невский проспект.**

**Несмотря на то, что Ягозин был кровным детищем Петербурга, дышал со дня рождения воздухом Невского проспекта и сосал молоко охтенской кормилицы, он весь тем не менее состоял из одной быстроты и юркости. Д. Григорович, Карьерист.**

**Мы принялись бегать по закрайку самого берега, и всё выходило отлично, несмотря на то что кое-где лед ломался и выступала вода. Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Дурной товарищ. Ботаническим садом управлял отличный ученый директор и не допускал никакого беспорядка, несмотря на то, что большую часть своего времени проводил в занятиях с микроскопом в особой стеклянной будочке, устроенной в главной оранжерее. В. Гаршин, Attalea Princeps.**

**Зритель должен был поверить, что перед ним человек, остающийся невредимым, несмотря на то что сквозь него пропускают токи необычайной силы. Ю. Олеша, Зрелища.**
*Прил.3.*

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за ответ, с Вами мне действительно интересно обсудить эту тему. Она не умещается в комментарии, посмотрите, пожалуйста, в дополнении к ответу.